# How can i get my gallery to look different for each user?

Tags: php, codeigniter, gallery

Hi again :) Im trying for each user to be able to upload their own version of a gallery to their own profile but when I do the same gallery appears within each profile. As a result of trying to do this the same gallery not only appears but I also get a this error: 
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I am also aiming to load each gallery image into a gallery for each user in a database and the images are already storing correctly in my file upload directory

Here is my gallery controller:

```
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {



function index()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $image = $this->session->userdata('images');

    $this->load->model("gal_model");

    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {

        $this->gal_model->do_upload();
        $this->gal_model->putGalleryImage($username, $image);

    }




    $viewData['username'] = $username;

    $data['images'] = $this->gal_model->get_images();
    //var_dump($data);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $data);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');


}
```

Here is my gallery model:

```
   class Gal_model extends CI_Model
   {
var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Gal_model()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/gallery';
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'web-project-jb/assets/gallery/';
}   


function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("gallery")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}




function do_upload ()
{
   $config = array(
  'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
  'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
  'max_size'   => 10000     
            );


    $this->load->library("upload", $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();


    $image = 'gallery_path'.$image_data['file_name'];

    $data['image'] = 'gallery_path'.$image_data['file_name'];


    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->gal_model->putGalleryImage($username, $image);

    $config = array(
        'source_image'  => $image_data["full_path"],
        'new_image'     => $this->gallery_path. '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration'   => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100     


            );

    $this->load->library("image_lib", $config);
   $this->image_lib->resize();
}


function get_images()
{
    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $images[] = array(
            'url'   => $this->gallery_path_url.$file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url.'thumbs/'.$file


                );

    }

    return $images;
}



function putGalleryImage($username, $image)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'galleryimage' => $image);
    $this->session->set_userdata($image);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('gallery', $record);


    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);

    }

   }

   }
```

Here is my gallery view:

```
   <div id="gallery">

   <?=if (isset($images)): 
   foreach($images as $image): ?>
   <div class="thumb">
       <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
          <img src ="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>"/>
       </a>  
       <br>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; else:  ?>
    <div id = "blank_gallery">Please upload an Image</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
   <?=form_open_multipart('gallery');?>
    <?=form_upload("userfile");?>
    <?=form_submit('upload', 'Upload')?>
    <?=form_close();?>
```

Thanks again for the help guys, I just need to know the right way to go out this :).

Comment: Is your getImages actually returning anything? var $gallery_path; var is a javascript way of doing things, I'm not the most knowledgeable PHP guy but I have never seen it used in PHP. Usually when declaring variables like that it's Public, Private or Protected not var.

Comment: @RickCalder The `var` keyword is used to [declare variables in a class in PHP 4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php):

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` can happen if you try to do a foreach on an variable that isn't an array. For removing that warning message update the gallery view to :

```
<div id="gallery">
   <?=if ( is_array($images) && (count($images)>0) ): 
       foreach($images as $image): ?>
           <div class="thumb">
               <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                  <img src ="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>"/>
               </a>  
               <br>
           </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php else:  ?>
        <div id = "blank_gallery">Please upload an Image</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<div>
```

I am not familiar with CI, but where do the `$images` get the values from?

Comment: Am i right in saying the $files variable? thanks for the feedback :). Is it correct to say that each isnt an array since I would be uploading oen file at a time?

Comment: i think you are doing it right. According to CI documentation `if we pass $data['price'] to the view, we can reference that using $price in the view itself; if we pass $data['description'], we can reference it in the view using $description, etc` [link](http://www.ntchosting.com/php/frameworks/codeigniter/#Views). What is the result of  `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: actually `$data['images']` will always an array since you are setting `$images = array();` in `function get_images()`, you only have to check if the count of array is greater than zero.

Comment: is this the line doing this: <?=if ( is_array($images) && (count($images)>0) ):

Comment: This is what the vardump throws back. Note it starts with an images array of 13 which is the amount i have uploaded so far and it is followed by the image I have uploaded first:array(1) { ["images"]=> array(13) { [0]=> array(2) { ["url"]=> string(67) "http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb/assets/gallery/Chrysanthemum.jpg" ["thumb_url"]=> string(74) "http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb/assets/gallery/thumbs/Chrysanthemum.jpg" }

Comment: I hope this is of help Nadakumar. I am still getting the foreach error when I upload an image by the way

Comment: The line no. where the warning occurs will be specified in the message itself like `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/index.php on line 4` . This will give you a good idea where is the issue. checking `is_array()` & `count()` will solve the warning message..